# Normalizing a Cauchy Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

all.  I'm trying to check in the following distribution is normalized, and am having a difficult time integrating it. If anyone can give me a clue on where to begin the integration, that be great.

The function in question is the Cauchy probability density function. I.e.,

$$ p(x) = \frac{a}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)}$$

Beginning my integration, I have:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} | p(x) |^2 dx & =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg | \frac{a}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)} \bigg |^2 dx \\
& = \bigg ( \frac{a}{\pi} \bigg )^2  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg | \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2} \bigg |^2 dx \end{align}$$

Unfortunately, this is as far I got. Would factoring out the $a^2$ term and using u-substitution for $u=x/a$ work for this?

Thanks.

Comment: you really don't need absolute values, right ?

Comment: @Kosta: If you only want to check that the Cauchy distribution is normalized, then you only need to check that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\frac{a}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)}} \mathrm{d}x = 1$. Why did you need to use absolute values?

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Why are you squaring $p(x)$?. You want to choose $a$ such that $p$ integrates to $1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I was confused. In Quantum Mechanics, normalizing means integrating $|\Psi|^2 = \Psi^* \Psi$. I tried doing the same for $p(x)$ before realizing that the $|\Psi|^2$ is a probability distribution. It was an oversight that I was stuck on for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your integral using the [reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) as
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x =\dfrac{x}{2a^2\left(x^2+a^2\right)}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-4}{\dfrac{1}{2a^2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
Solve ${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ by using the change of variable $u = \frac{x}{a}$, which will become 
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{a}{a^2u^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{\dfrac{1}{a}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{\arctan\left(u\right)}{a}=\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{a}$$
Therefore
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{2a^3}+\dfrac{x}{2a^2\left(x^2+a^2\right)}+C$$
Taking the integral limits, you get
$${\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}}\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2a^3}$$