# Calculating $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx $

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to prove that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2a^3}$

Using partial fraction decomposition on $ \frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)^2} $, and defining a contour $ \gamma_R $ to be the line segment between −R and R, together with a semicircle around $0$ of radius R. Using Cauchy's integral formula and the winding number of the appropriate points, I solved it.

However, it was a lot of algebra.
I wanted to ask, are there different ways to prove the statement?

Comment: There is one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912714/1163258.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{a}$$
and then
$$ I'(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-2a}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx = -\frac{\pi}{a^2}$$
Hence
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2a^3}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here are three other methods.

1. Change of variable $x=a\tan t$
2. Letting $I_a:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx $ and $J_a:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx$, show (by change of variable $y=\frac1x$) that $a^2I_a=J_a$, so that $2a^2I_a=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx$
3. Letting $f_a(x):=\operatorname e^{-a|x|}$ and $g_a(y)=\frac a{a^2+x^2}$, we find $\widehat{f_a}=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}g_a$, from which we derive $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(a^2+x^2)^2}=\frac1{a^2}g_a*g_a(0)=\frac\pi{a^2}g_{2a}(0)=\frac\pi{2a^3}$.